# Is Korra still considered as Aang’s incarnation

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

As we know, since rejoining with Raava, Korra is the beginning of a new avatar cycle. However, Is Korra no longer a incarnation of Aang and all the other past avatars now that her connection to them is severed. Aang’s spirit was reborn into her. Does her broken connection change that fact.

Answer (score 8):

Korra is still the reincarnation of Aang, the connection between the is simply severed.
She was already born before she was unfused, so the spirit that resides inside her, was already (previously) Aang's.

Unfusing and refusing with Ravah did not suddenly kill her spirit and give her a new one.

Comment: +1. Many reincarnation beliefs don't include past-life memories, and most don't include being able to have a conversation with your previous self.  Korra just went from "reincarnated and connected" to "reincarnated and disconnected."